# Bing map template with telerik map UI and Blazor

Tags: dictionary, telerik, blazor

Can you help me how to add Bing map tile to telerik map UI with blazor  , because I coudn't do that with https url like for openstreet map ?

Comment: Please provide information on what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think that bing uses a different standard than what the telerik blazor map uses at the moment (https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/map/layers/tile) so you may want to open a new enhancement request for support for bing to be added

And/Or, for the time being use an older component that already has such support like kendo https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/map/bing
You can also integrate kendo widgets in blazor: https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/knowledge-base/jquery-kendo-in-blazor

Comment: I'm going to try  kendo UI solution, thank you.